# facebook graph api post to page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page in facebook as well as an app for it.
I have generated a never expire token for the page , and tried to post to the page using the graph api  POST /me/feed

However, the messages i posted only appears if i query /me/feed in the graph api but not on the page wall. Why is this happening?

result for /me/feed

```
  {
  "id": "**********", 
  "from": {
    "category": "Education", 
    "name": "**************", 
    "id": "**************"
  }, 
  "message": "ok", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/**********"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/************"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE", 
    "friends": "", 
    "networks": "", 
    "allow": "", 
    "deny": ""
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
  "application": {
    "name": **********", 
    "id": "************"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2015-02-01T05:26:29+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2015-02-01T05:26:29+0000"
}, 
{
  "id": "825588500832993_846332195425290", 
  "from": {
    "category": "Education", 
    "name": "************", 
    "id": "825588500832993"
  }, 
  "message": "asd", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/*************"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/**************"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Public", 
    "value": "EVERYONE", 
    "friends": "", 
    "networks": "", 
    "allow": "", 
    "deny": ""
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
  "application": {
    "name": "**********", 
    "id": "**************"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2015-02-01T05:22:02+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2015-02-01T05:22:02+0000"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem, go to developers.facebook.com-> your app -> settings-> fill up email , then go to status & review -> switch the off button to on to make it live